# Console Errors While Looping Through JSON Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a very simple function that loops through some JSON data and adds the data to a list:

```
function printData(file) {
    $.getJSON('json/' + file, function(data) {
        for( var i=0; i <= data.agencies.length; i++ ) {
            $('#results').append(
                '<li class="group">' +
                    '<div class="agency-logo"><img src="images/agency_logos/' + data.agencies[i].logo + '" alt="' + data.agencies[i].name + '" /></div>' +
                    '<div class="agency-info">' + data.agencies[i].name + '<br />' +
                    data.agencies[i].address + '<br />' +
                    data.agencies[i].city + ', '  + data.agencies[i].state + ' '+ data.agencies[i].zip + '<br />' +
                    data.agencies[i].phone + '<br />' +
                    data.agencies[i].email + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="agency-desc">' + data.agencies[i].description + '</div>' +
                '</li>'
            );
        }
    });
}
```

JSON data:

```
{
"agencies" : [
    {
        "name"          : "Test Agency",
        "address"       : "283 Main Street",
        "city"          : "Danbury",
        "state"         : "CT",
        "zip"           : "06810",
        "phone"         : "(555) 555-5555",
        "email"         : "name@website.com",
        "description"   : "This is the description.",
        "logo"          : "logo.gif"

    },
    {
        "name"          : "Test Agency",
        "address"       : "100 Oak Street",
        "city"          : "Roseland",
        "state"         : "NJ",
        "zip"           : "06810",
        "phone"         : "(444) 444-4444",
        "email"         : "name@website.com",
        "description"   : "This is the description.",
        "logo"          : "logo.gif"
    }
]
}
```

Everything is working and outputting as it should, however I am getting a console error on whatever is the first item that I am outputting: (I assume that I would get error on each call, but the JS stops being parsed at the error.)

TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'data.agencies[i].logo')

This is my first time trying out outputting via JSON, so I am sure that I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS is fine. It's your loop that is incorrect

```
for( var i=0; i <= data.agencies.length; i++ )
```

should be

```
for( var i=0; i < data.agencies.length; i++ )
                ^ notice this change
```

You're trying to access the logo property of a null object.

**Edit**

Arrays are 0 indexed. This means that the first element is accessed using 0:

```
data.agencies[0] // <- returns the first element in the array
```

However, the `length` property returns the number of elements in the array. In this case, the `length` is returning 2.

In your original loop `for( var i=0; i <= data.agencies.length; i++ )` you'd get the following:

```
data.agencies[0]  // i is less than or equal to 2
data.agencies[1]  // i is less than or equal to 2
data.agencies[2]  // i is less than or equal to 2 and this returns null
```

Comment: that's right your objects length is 2 but your first index is 0 since you only have 2 'agencies' the index 2 is undefined

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was assuming that the length of the array started at 0. Thank you.

Comment: @user3427302. The length of the array **does** start at 0. I've updated my answer

Comment: @jasonscript Right, so wouldn't that mean that an alternate solution would be to start the index at 1? I tested that as well and still throws the error. Any idea why?

EDIT: This is answered below. Thanks.

Comment: @user3427302 if your started the index at 1 `i=1; i<= data.agencies.length; i++` you'd get lots of errors :) You wouldn't get the first `agency` value (`agencies[0]`) because i is never 0. Then your loop would try to get `agencies[1]` and `agencies[2]` and you would have the same error as before

Answer (score 0):

You are looping on an Array-based counting which starts by 0 . While the "Length" property is not a Zero-based counting property so it counts starting by 1.You need to do one of either modifications :

```
    for( var i=1; i <= data.agencies.length; i++ ) --> Works for looping thought non Zero-based data indexes
```

OR

```
    for( var i=0; i < data.agencies.length; i++ )  --> Works for JSON and Array-Based
```

Edit : First example will not work with looping through Array-based data like JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, starting the index at 1 does not resolve the issue and it still outputs the error. It also outputs one less item than it should. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Yes , Actually my answer isn't perfect when dealing with Array-Based content like JSON data .. as basically JSON is a piece of array and you need to deal with it the way you deal with arrays, starting index is 0 , so consider using my second example for your current problem where you need to start counting from 0 so that you can read index[0] inside your json array .